# Google App Script not invoking other function when run using triggers

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

A GAS that is updating a SQL query every day, suddenly started timing out so I decided to split the function in 2 and try chaining them by splitting the database in 2. To check where the first function left off, I added this function to look for the last empty row:

```
function getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange('A:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct+1);
};
```

This is then used to get this function to start writing at the connect line:

```
function Leden2() {
   var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(...);

 var SQLstatement = conn.createStatement();
 var result = SQLstatement.executeQuery("select concat (Firstname,' ', LastName), pla.team1, pla.team2, Birthday, Gender from account a right join player_info pla on pla.accountid = a.id where a.isactive = 1 and accountid>300");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Leden");

  var cell = sheet.getRange('A2');


  var row = getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray()-2;
  while (result.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < result.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(result.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
  }
```

If I run the 2 parts of the function manually it works perfectly (so Leden2 knows it has to start writing after the first function) but when I run it using a trigger Leden2 start at the first line.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your current issue, for example, when you modify `var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` to `var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Leden");` or `var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("###your expected sheet name###");`, will that be your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange('A1:A' + sh.getLastRow());
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  return (vs.length);
}
```